# Forgot password on submit leads to blank page

Tags: php, forgot-password

I am having an issue with my forgot password page.  When i enter in my email address and click submit i am brought to a blank page and an email with my password is not sent.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $email_address=$_POST['email_address'];
    $q=mysql_query("select * from login where email_address='".$email_address."' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $p=mysql_affected_rows();
    if($p!=0) 
    {
        $res=mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $to=$res['email_address'];
        $subject='YNAGS Password Recovery';
        $message='Your password : '.$res['password']; 
        $headers='From:password_reset@ynags.com';
        $m=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        if($m)
        {
            echo'Check your inbox in mail';
        }
        else
        {
            echo'mail is not send';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo'You entered mail id is not present';
    }
}
?>
```

I am not quite sure what this is here:

```
$q=mysql_query("select * from login where email_address='".$email_address."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

mainly the login part of this statement.

Comment: blank page means syntax errors, for which you are not checking for. Plus, it's obvious you're using an unsafe password storage method. Sending passwords like that tells me you're not running a safe site. You should be using a reset method.

Comment: In regards to your question: `I am not quite sure what this is here` - it's a security vulnerability (SQL injection) and you should change your code to use parameter binding before it's too late

Comment: thank you i will look into changing how i store passwords.  Right now i store them using md5 hash.  i guess i would not be able to grab them again anyways bc of this?  Is there a better way to encrypt them before entering them into database?

Comment: For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: thank you. i will implement this first and then continue on with my forgot password after

Comment: You're welcome. For now... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. It may be because of your POST arrays.

Answer (score -1):

1. We should know the code from db.php (obviously without the sensitive data).
2. Try something like this:

db.php

```
<?php
define("HOST", "your host");
define("USER", "db user name");
define("NAME", "db name");
define("PASSWORD", "password");
?>

forgot.php

<?php 
include("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['email_address'])){
    $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, NAME);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email_address = '".$email_address."'";
    if(mysqli_affected_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) != 0){
        $res = array();
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $sql));
        $to = $res['email_address'];
        // and so on ...
    }else{
        echo "Email not found";
    }
}else{
    echo "Form not submitted";
}
?>
```